# How to drop the Rows in a sql table for a particular string value

Tags: mysql, sql

The sql query `SELECT * FROM StudentRecord WHERE courseName like "SCIENCE";` gives me all the rows in the `studentRecord` table's column has "SCIENCE".

What is the query if I want to fetch all the rows in the table except where "SCIENCE" is there?

Comment: What does the column `courseName` contain, is it JUST "SCIENCE" or are you using the LIKE because you have things like "SOCIAL SCIENCE" and "BIOLOGICAL SCIENCE"

Comment: Did you try a simple `NOT LIKE "SCIENCE"` or as I might hazard a guess `WHERE != "SCIENCE"`

Comment: @RiggsFolly it is just "SCIENCE". But my interest in not in fetching what is related to "SCIENCE", it is the rows that do not have "SCIENCE"

Comment: Yes, so you should NOT be using LIKE you should be doing `WHERE courseName = "SCIENCE"` and the inverse `WHERE courseName != "SCIENCE"`

Comment: `!=` worked. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM StudentRecord 
WHERE courseName NOT LIKE "SCIENCE%";
```

you can try this way

ıf you want more info check this doc

https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-like/

Comment: Small point, there is no `%` after SCIENCE in the original question and in fact the OP should have been using `=` not `like`

Comment: I thought it might solve your problem if filters out words starting with SCIENCE )